# Static library and duplicate symbols:

Tags: c++, linker, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a general question about static library and duplicate symbols topic:
For example there are two static libraries:
one library is:
`staticLibA.a` which include one static library `base.a`
the other library is:
`staticLibB.a` which include same static library `base.a`

And if there is an application needs include both `staticLibA.a` and `staticLibB.a` and in this case both `staticLibA` and `staticLibB` lib contain the symbols of `base.a`, I wonder if in this case it will have duplicate symbols error?

From what I understand in this case, it will not have duplicate symbols issue, since duplicate symbols only be checked during the compile time. in this particular case, the application just needs to link against `staticLibA.a` and `staticLibB.a`. Although both of then have `base.a`. it seems ugly. but it will work. the `base.a` symbols in either `staticLibA.a` or `staticLibB.a` will be linked in the application.

I wonder if this is correct? and if someone have recommended reading materials describe more details about this topic?